# Saving large blob data to GridFS using Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, gridfs

I am attempting to make a slideshow web app that will be used on a LAN, so load times shouldn't be a big concern.

I've used [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) to generate my boiler plating.

I've looked around at some solutions and found [mongoose-fs](https://github.com/rricard/mongoose-fs), which functionality seems to be what I'm looking for. But I can't seem to get it to work. I've read through the source code and it all seems to make sense.

The problem is in my post API, despite that the req.body has req.body.music which contains a large 22MB mp3, the slide variable in the Slide.create doesn't have a slide.music property.

Is there something I'm missing or is there a better solution to save large files to GridFS?

Here is what my schema looks like

```
"use strict";

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongooseFS = require("mongoose-fs");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SlideSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    imgData: Buffer,
    interval: Number
});

var SlideCollection = new Schema({
    name: String,
    slideshow: [SlideSchema]
});

SlideCollection.plugin(mongooseFS, {keys: ["music"]});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Slide", SlideCollection);
```

My controller's POST API looks like this

```
// Creates a new slide in the DB.
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    Slide.create(req.body, function(err, slide) {
        if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        return res.status(201).json(slide);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get mongoose-fs to work, but I found [mongoose-gridstore](https://github.com/dlemon/mongoose-gridstore) which is based off of mongoose-fs and seems to be simple enough (or at least well documented enough) for me to use. I had to rewrite my POST API to make it work, but so far it is giving me the functionality I want, which is to upload large mp3s.

I'd also like a more dynamic schema to handle uploading large images too, but I think the 16mb limitation would be workable for right now.

This is what my schema looks like now.

```
"use strict";

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var gridStore = require("mongoose-gridstore");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SlideSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    imgData: String,
    interval: Number
});

var SlideCollection = new Schema({
    name: String,
    slideshow: [SlideSchema]
});

SlideCollection.plugin(gridStore);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Slide", SlideCollection);
```

And here is the new POST API

```
// Creates a new slide in the DB.
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var slide = new Slide({
        name: req.body.name,
        slideshow: req.body.slideshow
    });

    slide.addAttachment(req.body.name, String(req.body.music))
        .catch( function(err) { handleError(res, err); } );

    slide.save(function(err, post) {
        if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }

        return res.status(201).json(post);
    });
};
```

And just for completeness sake, here is the GET too

```
// Get a single slide
exports.show = function(req, res) {
    Slide.findById(req.params.id, function (err, slide) {
        if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        if(!slide) { return res.status(404).send("Not Found"); }
        slide.loadAttachments()
            .then(function(doc) {
                return res.json(doc);
            })
            .catch(function(loadingErr) {
                throw loadingErr;
            });
    });
};
```

Then in Angular I need to get the response.attachements[0].buffer to access the binary data to do whatever I need to do with it.